# Toggleclass highlighted with dynamic colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a JS function which allows me to set Table TDs highlighted by the toggleclass.

I would like to use different colors for highlighting and the colors shall be picked by clicking a div and select its BG Color.

The table and the Divs with colors are all generated dynamically by PHP. (The Colors are also selected out of database so CSS classes wont work).

I tried the following - By generating the "Colorpicker DIVS" i give them the hexcode as ID so i can use the ID as color in JQUERY.... When i highlight TDs now and click in one of the divs, all highlighted TDs become the clicked DIVs BG Color.

Actually i need it the other way around --- click the "Colorpick-div" and then dye the clicked TDs by the selected DIVS Background color.

Hopefully you understand what i mean. :-)

This is the Toggleclass JS:

```
$(function () {

  var isMouseDown = false,
      isHighlighted;

  $(document).on('mousedown', '#fullTable td', function() {
      isMouseDown = true;
      $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
      isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
      return false; // prevent text selection
    })

    .on('mouseover', '#fullTable td', function () {
      if (isMouseDown) {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);
      }
    })

    .bind("selectstart", function () {
      return false;
    })

  $(document)
    .mouseup(function () {
      isMouseDown = false;
    });

});
```

And this here i tried with JQUERY:

```js
$(document).on("click", "div.actions", function (event) {
    var bgcolor = this.id;
    $("td.highlighted").css("background-color", bgcolor);
});
```

Comment: So store the hex code into a variable, when one of your color divs gets clicked. Then color your table cells with the color from that variable, when they get mouse-overed …

Comment: Be aware an `id` can't start with a number. `id="000"` is not valid. An alternative are `data` attributes.

Comment: actually the HexCodes start with a # :-)

Comment: @mat_script id should be unique on the page and don't contain special characters(#)

Comment: `#` is also not valid. Has to start with a letter ;-)

Comment: Do you need to change color for all td.highlighted?

Comment: No, i want to first pick the color and then highlight the clicked TDs with the picked color.
And you guys are right - i still wonder that it picks the right colors atm.

Comment: @kmgt Not true at all. In HTML5 you can start the ID with a number or even a number alone.

Comment: @Roko I checked it on [w3c validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) and it passed even with any other character expect space. So you are right, it is not deprecated [w3/html5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute). Getting old, thanks for remember ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to change color for all highlighted cells, this may not work on all versions of JQuery!

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $(':root').css('--bgColor', 'green');
}, 2000);
```

```css
:root {  
  --bgColor: crimson;
}
div{
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 10px;
}

.highlighted {
  background-color: var(--bgColor);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="highlighted"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="highlighted"></div>
```